# JQuery Sortable: Can I treat two rows as one row when dragging to another position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table layout like so:

```
<table name="table" class="table table-striped pagin-table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td class="colour" colspan="2">Options</td>           
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="table-tr draggable">
                    <td class="duration">1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                    <td>                            
                        <a class="btn btn-small btn-info" style="margin:auto; display:block;" href="{{ URL::to('mods/' . $value->id . '/edit') }}">Edit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="table-tr draggable">
                    <td colspan="10">Team</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
</table>
```

and a Jquery Sortable function like so:

```
$( "tbody" ).sortable({ 
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var ids = new Array();
            $('tr', this).each(function () {
                ids.push($(this).data('id'));
            });
            $.get(window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "/sort", {ids: ids});
        }
});
```

For this table, I'm using JQuery Sortable so I can move the rows around. However, my sortable function moves each individual row, where I want it to group the two  rows and have them move together:

```
|----1----|----2----|----3----|----4----|----5----|----6----|-Options-|
|--------------------------------Team---------------------------------|
```

I've tried grouping the rows together using HTML but it breaks and doesn't move both the rows together. I've also tried to modify my function so that it refers to everything inside the 'tbody' tag, but it still treats the two different 'tr' tags as seperate rows.

If anyone has any insight, please let me know! Thanks!

**EDIT: (To Clarify)**

My table has two rows, and I want JQuery Sortable to treat them as one row for the purposes of sorting/dragging it to another position. Alternatively, if I can create one row, and split into two so that the numbers/options are on top, and the team is on the bottom, that will also work.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sort column on click event then my below code helps you.

```
function sortTable(n, selector) {
    var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
    ///table = document.getElementById(selector);
    table = $(selector);
    switching = true;

    //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
    dir = "asc";
    /*Make a loop that will continue until
    no switching has been done:*/
    while (switching) {
        //start by saying: no switching is done:
        switching = false;
        rows = $(table).find('tr'); ///table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
        /*Loop through all table rows (except the
        first, which contains table headers):*/
        for (i = 0; i < (rows.length - 1) ; i++) {
            //start by saying there should be no switching:
            shouldSwitch = false;
            /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
            one from current row and one from the next:*/
            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
            /*check if the two rows should switch place,
            based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
            if (x != null && y != null) {
                if (dir == "asc") {
                    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (dir == "desc") {
                    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
            /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
            and mark that a switch has been done:*/
            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
            switching = true;
            //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
            switchcount++;
        } else {
            /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
            set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
            if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                dir = "desc";
                switching = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I've got the sorting to work, it's more to do with the fact that I can't get it to move the **two** rows together and treat it as one. At the moment, it treats each individual 'tr' tag as a seperate row regardless of if it's in the 'tbody' tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table>
<tbody >
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2" class="duration">1</td>
                    <td rowspan="2"  >2</td>
                    <td rowspan="2"> 3</td>
                    <td rowspan="2" >4</td>
                    <td rowspan="2" >5</td>
                    <td rowspan="2" >6</td>
                    <td rowspan="2" ><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                    <td rowspan="2" >                            
                        <a class="btn btn-small btn-info" style="margin:auto;" href="{{ URL::to('mods/' . $value->id . '/edit') }}">Edit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="table-tr draggable">
                    <td colspan="8">Team</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

show this look like this ( **1 2 4 5 6 checkox edit team** )

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. The issue still occurs regardless of whatever the rowspan is. My question is can I get Jquery Sortable to treat the two 'trs' as one row when it is being dragged, and treat it as one row.